# GPU post maintenance

Tags: discussion

It's been a while since we made [Enabling GPU rendering for Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7485/599), and a few things have changed since then (opencl support has come a long way, but also has more than a few issues worth documenting). As the main answer is already quite lengthy, I propose splitting it into separate answers by operating system and GPU manufacturer. That way we can link to the instructions more precisely and supply an index like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/599).

Since it would be a little weird to make the current highly-upvoted answer specific to a particular operating system + manufacturer, I suggest putting the index there. Hopefully it remains on top, or if not, we can link to it instead of the question.

Unfortunately, this does mean breaking the edit history up. Spelling out credits for everyone who contributed in each new answer would probably generate excessive noise, so, perhaps people who contributed a section before might like to author the answer for that section?

Otherwise, if there are no objections, I can start splitting things up tomorrow.

Comment: (Coming from me, an infrequent user of this site) Thank you for taking the time to keep questions and answers up to date and keeping some indispensable information organized.

Answer (score 3):

I have not contributed to the answer in question, but I will say that I see three possibilities for this.

First off that CW answer should not be the index. The index belongs in the question. There are three sorting methods for answers, we have no way of knowing if the "index answer" will be on top. Any index for a post like this needs to be in the question.

Having established that we are left with three options.

1. Delete it. I know sounds crazy, but hear me out. Any information in it (that's not outdated) will be in its corresponding new answer. The most recant comment was from 19 months ago, and there is nothing really needed there. Gandalf you are the original author you would be the one starting the new answers, so no problem with authorship.
2. Convert it to one of the new sections (say the windows answer). But how do we choose which platform gets a 100 vote bonus offer the others, the new answers?
3. Lock this post and start a new one. Like you said some things have changed. We could lock this as historical, and link people to the new clean post. (Seams better then deleting an answer, and solves the lost revision history issue.)

---

How many answers are we talking here? Will it be just Win, Linux, and OSX, **3** answers. Or will it be Win cuda, Win opencl, Win intel; Linux cuda, Linux opencl, Linux intel; and OSX cuda, OSX opencl, OSX intel, **9** answers?

I'm not sure which is better. I think if we go with the new post then just split it all up.

If we do decide that all nine answer is better and we keep using this post, then I think the standing answer should get retired (deleted).

Comment: The index answer would be the best, because it would have all the information inside it. So it should be voted up as the most helpful. And if this is not the case and there is answer more helpful, be it. That would only show the proposed structure of indexing is not working and people want something else.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny SE's format is not great for this type of info post. If there is any point to have an index, it needs to be first. (If you are using a Mac, then you will not care *at all* about the Linux or Win answers, even if they are voted higher.) As I said in my answer, 
there are three different ways to sort answers: *active*, *oldest*, and *votes*. We have no way of keeping any set order to the answers. I think an index is a good idea. People coming from google can find the section they need. However for that index to be any good it needs to be in the question.

Comment: So don't try to make info post that does not work in SE's format, tailor it so it works with the system and not against it - the logic needs to work like this: a general question and an answer for it that covers all the cases inside it (not multiple answers for each case). Because such answer would be too long, it will be just bunch of links to other specific questions with each having answers. Like Enabling GPU rendering on Mac, Enabling GPU rendering on Linux, etc. Also for each such specific question, there might be multiple ways how to get it working.

Comment: See [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91784/7777) as an example - I linked another question in the answer, because it was already covered there. What if all the cases of GPU enabling were covered on SE already and someone asked a general question? You would just post an answer full of links to those and the answer itself would not have much more content than that. Pls do not try to bend the site into being a wiki site, it is not, the result would be ugly.

Comment: As long as the score doesn't go too low (!) the accepted answer should stay on top. I don't like the idea of deleting the main answer as that would erase pretty much all traces of who contributed what..

Comment: To clarify, I am thinking more along the lines of your 9 answer example. I chose GPU manufacturer instead of CUDA/OpenCL though, as, say, someone on Linux with an Nvidia GPU may very well be interested in setting up both CUDA and OpenCL. Also, as the instructions for linux differ a bit between flavors, there will likely be more than 9 answers (e.g. separate debian and arch answers).

Comment: Regarding starting a new post, that will break all existing links to the current post. Sure, we could link to the new post from the existing one (or close as duplicate), but I'm not sure it's worth putting an extra "manual redirect" in the chain.

Comment: @gandalf3 I think it's important to preserve the original. There may be information that is still relevant to some people. I would either keep the anwswer and edit it to make it clear this is 'legacy' information or make a new question and close the old as a duplicate.

Comment: @RayMairlot The content won't change, it'll just be split into separate answers. When the answers are edited/updated, sure, old information will be hidden in the edit history, but it's still there (and no different from how the current single answer works). If the current answer were mostly obsolete I'd agree with archiving and moving on, but for the most part I don't think that's the case. If we were to completely rewrite all of it the end result would probably look pretty similar.